# dimension of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $ T\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Let $V$ be the subspace of $M_{n\times p}(\mathbb R)$ defined by

$$V= \{X\in M_{n\times p}(\mathbb R): TX=O \} $$
 Find the dimension of $V$

There will be $m$ equations for $n$ variables, i.e. total $mp$ equations for $np$ variables. But now I got stuck. Kindly help.

Comment: Is $T$ assumed to be of full rank?

Comment: No,  T can have rank strictly less than min{ m, n} too.

Comment: If you know the answer for $p=1$, you should have no difficulty to find the answer for a general $p$.